# In simple linear regression model, why do we calculate the confidence interval for slope parameter using t-distribution?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, regression-coefficients, t-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I'm taking a regression analysis course and we were studying simple linear regression.
I've understood how slope

$$
\hat\beta_1 follows \space N(0,\sigma^2 / S_{xx})
$$

and is normally disributed.

And

$$
\hat\sigma^2 follows \space \sigma^2 * \chi(n-2) / (n-2)
$$

the estimated sigma^2 follows a chi square distribution.

but next he said that using this we can prove this term:

$$
(\hat\beta_1 - \beta_1)/se(\hat\beta_1)
$$

Follows a t-distribution with n-2 degrees of freedom and I'm not able understand how do I go from a normal distribution to t-distribution using the above two equations.

Edit : So upon googling a bit there seems to be some relationship between chi square and t-distribution but I'm still not able to follow the logic behind that and how this one will work out.

Comment: Have you seen how the t-distribution comes about as the ratio between a standard normal random variable and the square root of a chi square random variable divided by its degrees of freedom? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#How_the_t-distribution_arises_(characterization)

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Why not begin your experience with a site search?  [It will answer your question in many useful and insightful ways.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=distribution%20student%20t%20chi*&searchOn=3)